# ASP.NET MVC drag and drop designer example?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for an example implementation of a ASP.NET MVC-based, drag&drop designer surface. My googling skills are failing me, so I thought maybe someone has knowledge on an example implementation.

I'm not looking for a paint on canvas functionality - I'd rather have dragable and dropable shapes/images.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Have you checked jQuery UI?  https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: That looks cool, but I'm also looking for some extra features, like on-screen links between elements etc. Stuff you'd expect to see in a simple designer

Answer (score 1):

William Malone has a awesome tutorial about that, int tutorial he developed many functionalities and all very much explained.

Check it out:

[Create a Drawing App with HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app)

Comment: I was looking for something else rather then a paint app, although the tutorial is pretty brilliant, so +1 for this answer from me :)